# Getting Error when installing wordpress 4.1 on my xampp server

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I've been finding update issue when installing fresh wordpress.

I am running wordpress on my xampp. when i go to the appearance > themes folder. it through me an error:

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.
>
> (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php on line 295
>
> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.
>
> (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php on line 457
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1511

Please help!. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your computer should be connected to the internet in order for WP is being installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because of connection error.
Connect your PC with Internet & check it again.